# How to improve slow MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I know there's many questions/answers for slow queries, but I'm struggling to relate an existing answer to my example.

I have the following simple query which counts article views in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    articles.id,
    articles.views,
    articles.title,
    articles.slug,
    articles.created_at,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM tracking WHERE element_id = articles.id AND tracking_type = 'article_view') AS tracking_views                                  
FROM articles                                
WHERE articles.company_id = 123                                
ORDER BY articles.created_at DESC
```

This particular company has ~250 articles, and the query takes over 12 seconds.

Is there a better/more efficient way I could be doing this?

Comment: An important information that you should have taken away from those other questions/answers: you need to provide the execution plan (the output of `explain select ...` for your query) and details about your indexes (e.g. the output of `show create table articles` (and the same for `tracking`), optionally stripped by some columns if there are a lot of columns in your table that you don't use here - but don't remove indexes or columns used in indexes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining to a group by. Its pretty hard to say without knowing how many articles / views and companies there are though.

What you want is for SQL to be able to to the aggregation of `tracking` in one go, rather than individually for every row in the result, which is implied by the position of your `tracking_view` sub select.

If your lucky (I didnt check) the join to the `counts` sub select will be smart enough to skip any articles that are not for the right company. If not you can include the join back to company in the `counts` sub select.

eg

```sql
select a.*, counts.count
from articles a
join (
   select count(*) as count, element_id
   from tracking
   where tracking_type = 'article_view'
   group by tracking.element_id
) as counts on counts.element_id = a.id
where a.company_id = 123
ORDER BY articles.created_at DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for this, worked perfectly. That's brought the query down from over 12s to < 1s. I think I understand why - grouping them first and then selecting the total in one go rather than one by one. Makes sense!